# How do i add a continued text on the first row of the table body and not the table header in xsl fo?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to create dynamic tables in my pdfs using Apache FOP.
I have achieved most of it and require some fine tuning.
I have used the fo:retrieve-table-marker in the table header and it works perfectly.
But i do want the same continued text on the first row of the table body.
When i use the fo:retrieve-table-marker in the table body i get the below error :

(Location of error unknown)org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:fo:retrieve-table-marker" is not a valid child of "fo:block"! An fo:retrieve-table-marker is permitted only as the descendant of an fo:table-header or an fo:table-footer. (No context info available)

how do i achieve this?

here is my sample xsl :

```
<fo:table>
 <fo:table-header>
  <fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
   <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>
    <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="fortsSectionTitle" retrieve-position- within-table="first-starting"/>
                </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
   </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-header>
  <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="fortsSectionTitle"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="fortsSectionTitle">
                            <xsl:text>&#160;forts.</xsl:text>
                        </fo:marker>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        <!--this is my first row of table body -->
       <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
         <fo:block>
          <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="fortsSectionTitle" retrieve- 
 position-within-table="1"/>
         </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
       <fo:table-row>
       <!-- rest of my table rows with details -->
       ...
     </fo:table-body>
     </fo:table>
```

Desired output :

```
PAGE 1:

HEADER
1ST ROW OF TABLE BODY
.
.
.

PAGE 2:

HEADER cont.
1ST ROW OF TABLE BODY cont.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Could you not put the first row of the body put inside the fo:table-header and use some style to look like the body?

Comment: Your second `fo:retrieve-table-marker` in your sample is in the third row of the `fo:table-body`, not the first row as the comment says.

Comment: That is merely a table inside a table using omit to not show the first header and building the table with continued in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving markers inside an `fo:table-body` is not supported by the XSL 1.1 spec.

The spec says that an `fo:retrieve-table-marker` can be be used in place of an `fo:table-header` or `fo:table-footer` or inside an `fo:table-header` or `fo:table-footer`. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_retrieve-table-marker)

FWIW, Antenna House Formatter has an `axf:table-cell-repeated-marker` extension that can do what you want. (See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#table)

Comment: Somehow doesnt work and gives me the error : (Location of error unknown)org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Invalid property encountered on "fo:table-cell": axf:repeat-footnote-in-table-header (No context info available) :( :(

Comment: `FWIW, Antenna House Formatter` only. Not FOP.